# More than one possibility for the generator function of a Clayton's copula?

Tags: copula

This question is about the bivariate family of Clayton's copulas, defined as:

$$
C(u,v)=\left(u^{-\theta} + v^{-\theta}\right)^{-1/\theta} \; \text{,} \quad \quad \text{(1)}
$$

with $\theta \in [-1, +\infty[ \;\smallsetminus\; \{0\}$.

It is an Archimedean copula, meaning that it can be expressed in this form:

$$
C(u,v)= \varphi^{-1}\left( \varphi(u) + \varphi(v) \right) \; \text{,} \quad \quad \text{(2)}
$$

where $\varphi$ is a continuous, strictly decreasing, convex function from $[0,1]$ to $[0, +\infty]$, such that $\varphi(0)=+\infty$ (in the sense that $\lim_{t\rightarrow0^{+}}{\varphi(t)} = +\infty$) and $\varphi(1) = 0$.

In the case of the Clayton family, this $\varphi$, known as the *generator function* of $C$, has the following expression:

$$
\varphi(t) = \frac{1}{\theta}\left( t^{-\theta} -1 \right)
$$

—or, at least, that's what I thought.

However, I've also seen this other expression for the generator function of a Clayton's copula (I am calling it $\tilde{\varphi}$, just to differentiate it from $\varphi$):

$$
\tilde{\varphi}(t) = \left( t^{-\theta} -1 \right) \; \text{.}
$$

The respective inverse functions are:

$$
\varphi^{-1}(s) = (1 + \theta s)^{-1/\theta} \quad \text{and} \quad \tilde{\varphi}^{-1}(s) = (1 + s)^{-1/\theta} \; \text{.}
$$

If I am not wrong, both meet (1) and (2), I mean:

$$
\varphi^{-1}\left( \varphi(u) + \varphi(v) \right) = \tilde{\varphi}^{-1}\left( \tilde{\varphi}(u) + \tilde{\varphi}(v) \right) = \left(u^{-\theta} + v^{-\theta}\right)^{-1/\theta} \; \text{.}
$$

MY ORIGINAL QUESTION: So, **does this mean that there can be more than one generator function for a given Archimedean copula?**

CHECKING FOR THE DECREASE CONDITION: The only point of discussion is the fact that the first derivative of $\tilde{\varphi}$ is *not* negative when $\theta \in [-1, 0[$ (which corresponds to a negative or inverse association between $U$ and $V$, the two components of the copula). The original $\varphi$ does not show such a problem; it is always decreasing for any value of $\theta \in [-1, +\infty[ \;\smallsetminus\; \{0\}$.

CHECKING FOR THE CONVEXITY CONDITION: And, besides this, the same happens with the second derivatives. The second derivative of $\varphi$ is always nonnegative (which is a necessary and sufficient condition for convexity), while the second derivative of $\tilde{\varphi}$ is only nonnegative when $\theta >0$.

MY NEW QUESTION: So **does this mean that $\tilde{\varphi}$ is also a valid generator function for Clayton's copulas if we are limited to nonnegative associations or correlations?**  (i.e., $\theta >0$)

MY FINAL THOUGHT: **In which context does $\tilde{\varphi}$ appear as an alternative to $\varphi$ in Clayton's copulas?**

---

**EDIT**

So, according to the comments that my question has got, there can be more than one generator function for a given copula (which I was not aware of). Actually, $\tilde{\varphi}$ would be a valid one for Clayton, only in the case of $\theta >0$.

The only question that is still open to me: **WHY? I mean, why are there two 'more famous' generator functions for a Clayton copula? In which context or at what moment did each of them appear or were used...? What advantages has $\tilde{\varphi}$ over $\varphi$, if any?**

Comment: If $\phi$ is a generator then $c\phi$ is also a generator for any $c>0$. This is stated without proof in theorem 4.1.5 of Nelsen's book. Here we take $c=\theta$ so the conclusion of this statement only holds for $\theta>0$.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent So you may want to put that as an answer?

Comment: Yes, can be more than one generator.